# "vermilion" or "vermillion"?

Tags: word-choice, orthography, doubled-consonants, colors

Which one has primacy in English: "vermilion" or "vermillion" (as a color) ? Both have entries in various dictionaries. Is the difference concerned with AmE/BrE ?

Comment: I live in Vermillion Township, Ashland County, Ohio. The Vermilion River rises in our county and has its mouth at the city of Vermilion, Ohio. But the 1857 Atlas listed it as the Vermillion River.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the single-L spelling is more popular on both sites of the pond, according to the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org):

```
              BNC   COCA

 vermilion     43    197
 vermillion     3     34
```

This is excluding proper names. If we include them, the picture doesn't change dramatically:

```
                        BNC   COCA

 vermilion/Vermilion     50    327
 vermillion/Vermillion    5    139
```

Answer (score 2):

According to *Webster's Third New International Dictionary of the English Language*, *vermilion* or *vermillion* is derived from,

> [ME *vermilioun*, fr. OF *vermeillon*, fr. *vermeil*, adj., bright red, fr. LL *vermiculus* kermes (scale from which red dyestuff is derived), fr. L, little worm, dim. of *vermis* worm -- more at WORM]

There may be something involved with the distinction of between l/ll in the derivation from ME/OF.

Interesting too that there are several cities in the United States that use both the l/ll spellings.

Here is an Ngram as well that clearly favors the single 'l' spelling:

[image]